# Thread safety on Int32/Int64 operations on 64-bit .net

Tags: .net, multithreading

I think I read that the operations on Int32 and Int64 are truly atomic on 64-bit systems (ie. the assembly/application is compiled as 64-bit) in .Net.

Is that true?

I can not find the MSDN citation, so I thought I'd ask you guys here.

I'm wondering if to use the Interlocked class to check and decrement the value of an Int32 from multiple threads or not, and I'm compiling it as a 64-bit application.

There's a little help in a documentation of these methods on MSDN, but I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "use the interlocked class"?

Comment: It means to use System.Threading.Interlocked class to decrement the value of an Int32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re incrementing a value:

A manual *increment* ***is never*** guaranteed to be atomic - not on x86, not on x64; it is four operations: load, load, add, store. The JIT might spot a load-constant-1 (`ldc_i4_1` / `ldc_i8`) and make it a bit simpler, but fundamentally: that is not a single atomic operation. You **cannot** do a thread-safe increment (that does not risk lost updates) in multi-threaded code without using some kind of locking construct, or using `Interlocked`.

Re assignment atomicity (aka torn values):

Operations on `int` (etc) are guaranteed to be atomic by the language specification; operations on `long` (etc) ***are not guaranteed to be***. Yes, it likely that they *are* atomic on x64, but here's the rub: when worrying about atomicity, you must be dealing with threading. When dealing with threading, you **don't look** at the implementation, i.e. what *happens* to be - because that is ***not guaranteed***, and you presumably care that this code does what it intends. As such IMO you must only concern yourself with *what **is** guaranteed*, and that means: you can't rely on `long` (etc) being atomic.

Instead, use `Interlocked.Increment`, `Interlocked.Add`, etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this answer. I checked it in the MSIL code and you're right: (int) i++ used four steps: ldloc.0, ldc.i4.1, add, stloc.0.It's answers like these that make you understand what you are doing.

Comment: @grizzly in some ways you're not unreasonable in thinking their might be an "increment-by-one via this i4 / i8 reference"... and it could well be that the JIT does this behind the scenes.